# OS X Terminal - Find Text in Files Beginning With Variable

Tags: macos, bash, terminal

I need to search through a folder of files and copy all text that begins with a variable.

So for example:

Files A.txt,B.txt,C.txt, and D.txt contain the strings "Hello1", "Hello2", "Hello3", and "Hello4" respectively. I need to be able to search for all words that begin with "Hello" and output the result.

In this particular case A.txt,B.txt,C.txt, and D.txt would be searched and the output would be

```
Hello1
Hello2
Hello3
Hello4
```

I've looked around and found the following which allows me to export all files containing the text, however I'm not sure how or if this can be adapted for what I need.

```
grep -l Hello *.txt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want `grep -ohw 'Hello[0-9]*' *.txt`.

- `-o` only outputs the matching part of the line
- `-h` makes `grep` suppress filename output
- `-w` makes `grep` search for whole words only, so a `Hello1Hello2` would not be matched (it would be matched twice without `-w` though)

You need to adjust the pattern, since a literal `Hello` will only match `Hello` and subsequently just output that. Since you want to match `Hello1` through `Hello5` (or even `Hello123`), you need multiple digits (`[0-9]*`).

Don't forget to quote the pattern so the `*` is not expanded by the shell.

Comment: +1 for a right answer but I think the OP does not want the `-o` since he says "all text that _begins_ with a variable."

Comment: Could be. Their example is ambiguous in that regard. Let's see.

Comment: This is great, thank you! My example was a little simpler than what I actually needed. I ended up going with this.


grep -ohw 'FDRLocalizedString(@".*"' *.m

Answer (score 0):

This looks for words beginning with a variable.

```
var=Hello
grep -ho "\\<${var}[^[:blank:]]*" *.txt
```

grep's `\<` is the "start of word" anchor.

I assume that your words are blank delimited, so the rest of the word is non-blank characters. You can change this to numbers (`[0-9]*`) or perl-like "word characters" (`[[:alnum:]_]*`) easily enough.